# Maven repository for PayPal java API

Tags: maven, paypal, repository

I migrate a eclipse based project to maven based one.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>paypal-base</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

I need version 1.4.4 or later (because the original jar file we were using was version 1.4.4). But in public repositories I find only version 1.0.0.

EDIT: We solved this problem while ago by set-uping private repo. Seems that PayPal have finally uploaded their API [jars in  the official maven repo](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cpaypal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Maven way of solving this kind of problem is to set up your own Maven repository (e.g. [Sonatype Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/)). Then you can upload the artifacts you need.

The "quick and dirty" solution would be to copy the required Jar file into a folder and include this file as dependency by using the scope "system" ([see Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies))